# Show the following measure theory result.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $A$ be a unbounded Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $m(A) < \infty$. Show that for each $\epsilon > 0$,there exists a bounded Lebesgue measurable set $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $B \subset A$ and $m(A \setminus B)< \epsilon $. 

I have no idea how to approach these kind of problems.

Comment: *Hint.* What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} m(A\cap[-n,n])$?

Comment: can @SangchulLee explain a bit how to use that?

Comment: Write $B_n=A\cap[-n,n]$ for simplicity. Can you check that $m(B_n)\to m(A)$ as $n\to\infty$? Now if this is checked, then using $m(A)<\infty$ we find that $m(A\setminus B_n)\to0$. Why does this lead to the desired statement?

Comment: yes I understood. Thanks @SangchulLee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Monotone Convergence Theorem, we have $m(A\cap[-n,n])\rightarrow m(A)$. Now $m(A)<\infty$ allows us to have the estimate that $m(A)-m(A\cap[-n,n])<\epsilon$ for large $n$.